¿Cómo resolver el error Http 415 (Unsupported Media Type)?
Tengo una App con Angular y Springboot. La idea es poder crear una solicitud, en la que se pueda enviar un fichero PDF. A la hora de crearse la solicitud, el error que se muestra en la consola del navegador es este:  POST http://localhost:4200/api/solicitudes 415 (Unsupported Media Type) HttpErrorResponse {headers: _HttpHeaders, status: 415, statusText: 'Unsupported Media Type', url: 'http://localhost:4200/api/solicitudes', ok: false,
En la terminal, se muestra el siguiente error: HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarygzD5Ndo4sz35KRS4;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]
Código de SolicitudService.java:
 public Solicitud crearSolicitud(Solicitud solicitud, MultipartFile fichero) {
        if (fichero != null && !fichero.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                // Guardar el archivo en el escritorio del servidor
                String nombreArchivo = guardarArchivoEnEscritorio(fichero);
                solicitud.setNombreArchivo(nombreArchivo);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error al guardar el archivo.", e);
            }
        }
        
        solicitud.setFecha_solicitud(LocalDateTime.now());
        solicitud.setEstado_solicitud(TipoEstado.EN_TRAMITE);
        
        return solicitudRepository.save(solicitud);
    }

Código de SolicitudController.java:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/solicitudes")
public class SolicitudController {

    @Autowired
    private SolicitudService solicitudService;

    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    @PostMapping(consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity<Solicitud> crearSolicitud(@RequestPart("fichero") MultipartFile fichero, @RequestBody Solicitud solicitud) {
        try {
            Solicitud nuevaSolicitud = solicitudService.crearSolicitud(solicitud, fichero);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(nuevaSolicitud, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}

Para la parte de angular, tengo el siguiente código
fichero solicitud.service.ts:
  crearSolicitud(solicitud: Solicitud, file:File): Observable<Solicitud> {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('solicitud', JSON.stringify(solicitud));
  formData.append('fichero', file, file.name);

  const headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
  return this.http.post<Solicitud>(`${this.url}`, formData, {headers : headers});
}

fichero crear-solicitud.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { SolicitudService } from '../services/solicitud.service';
import { Solicitud } from '../models/Solicitud';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-crear-solicitud',
  templateUrl: './crear-solicitud.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crear-solicitud.component.css']
})
export class CrearSolicitudComponent implements OnInit {

  archivoSeleccionado: File | null = null;

  constructor(private solicitudService: SolicitudService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onFileSelected(event: any): void {
    this.archivoSeleccionado = event.target.files[0] as File;
  }

  crearSolicitud(solicitudForm: NgForm): void {
    if (solicitudForm.valid && this.archivoSeleccionado) {
      const solicitud: Solicitud = {
        fecha_solicitud: new Date(solicitudForm.value.fecha_solicitud),
        tipo_dia: solicitudForm.value.tipo_dia,
        id: 0,
        estado: '',
        user_id: 0,
        fichero: this.archivoSeleccionado
      };
  
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('fecha_solicitud', solicitud.fecha_solicitud.toString());
      formData.append('tipo_dia', solicitud.tipo_dia);
      formData.append('fichero', this.archivoSeleccionado, this.archivoSeleccionado.name);
  
      console.log("Datos: ", formData);
      
      this.solicitudService.crearSolicitud(solicitud, this.archivoSeleccionado).subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log("Solicitud creada con éxito:", response);
        },
        error => {
          console.error("Error al crear la solicitud:", error);
        }
      );
    } else {
      console.log("El formato de los campos no es válido o no se ha seleccionado ningún archivo");
    }
  }
  
}


buen dia, si estás enviando un form-data desde angular, debes recbir en el controller con @ModelAttribute necesariamente
    @PostMapping(value = "/solicitud")
    public ResponseEntity<Solicitud> crearSolicitud(@Valid @ModelAttribute 
    DatosDtoRequest vDatosDtoRequest) {
      try {
        Solicitud nuevaSolicitud = solicitudService.crearSolicitud(vDatosDtoRequest);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(nuevaSolicitud, HttpStatus.CREATED);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
      }
    } 

